# How to add ToXmlGenerator.Feature to Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson2

I have the `jackson` bean configuration below. How can I add the `ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION` feature to the builder?

The following does not work:

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer initJackson() {
    return (builder) -> builder.modules(new JaxbAnnotationModule())
                .defaultUseWrapper(false)   
                .featuresToEnable(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION); //invalid!

}
```

Result:

> Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter]:
>   Factory method 'mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter' threw
>   exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Unknown feature class:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.ser.ToXmlGenerator$Feature

My initial goal is to add the following line during deserialization:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.

Maybe there is a different way instead of using the `ToXmlGenerator`?

I also tried the following, but that does also NOT add the xml declaration line:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    XmlMapper mapper = (XmlMapper) builder
            .createXmlMapper(true)
            .build();

    mapper.configure(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, true);
    return mapper;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was close, but the `ObjectMapper` use for serialization of java beans to xml is not the one in the question. Instead in `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` a new mapper is created by spring autoconfiguration. This has to be overridden as follows:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    ObjectMapper mapper = builder.createXmlMapper(true).build();
    ((XmlMapper) mapper).enable(ToXmlGenerator.Feature.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION);
    return new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter(mapper);
}
```

Comment: you could simplify the code by just declaring `mapper` as `XmlMapper`